# Provide modified uploaded file as download AngularJS NodeJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, download, filenames

I have a Multer upload in my frontend:

```
<form  id="uploadForm" ng-submit="upload.submit">
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file" >
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >
</form>
```

in my upload controller:

```
this.submit = function(){
            $http.post('/upload').then(function success(response){
            }, function error(response){
})
}
```

upload NodeJS with Multer:

```
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
       destination: function (req, file, cb) {
         cb(null, '../uploads);
       },
       filename: function (req, file, cb) {
         cb(null,  file.originalname);
       }
    });

var upload = multer({ storage : storage});

router.post('/upload', upload.single('file'),  function(req, res, next){

    if(!req.file) {
        res.status(400);
        res.send({error: 'Datei nicht vorhanden'});
      }
    res.send({filename: req.file.filename});
})  ;
```

how can I get this file name in a nother `router.get` request?

In my NodeJS I'm saving the file to the server, so I know that path. (../uploads/)

I want to provide the downloaded file for an download to the client again with `<a href="http://<path to file>">Download</a>` but how do I get the filename the user uploaded ? 
To make this download work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are using angular you have to get rid of "action", "method", "enctype". Handle the form submittion in your controller and there you will receive a response.

Comment: I do use a controller added it above.

Comment: I meant your angularjs controller. Anyway in your backend /upload function you should be returning the uploaded file name

Comment: added the angular controller above. but how can I get the file name which changes because the clients dont upload a file with the same name. To provide the file downloaded to the server to upload to the client. There for I need the exact file name.

Comment: You return the file name from your server. Check my answer, there are several things you are going about the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, your form is wrong.
Check out angularJs form submittion: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

As for your file upload, check this:  https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

I noticed you are using multer, here you have an example from an app of mine:

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/images/banks')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
      cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname));
    });
  }
});
var upload = multer({storage: storage});

router.post('/uploadImage', upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) {
  if(!req.file) {
    res.status(400);
    res.send({error: 'No se pudo subir el archivo'});
  }

  res.send({filename: req.file.filename});
});
```

With this three things you should be able to upload a file and receive back its name.
Start slowly and step by step and you will make it work.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. But when I submit the download a new page with {"filename":"Untitled Document 1"} appears. Why does it open a new page and how can I make it not load a new page?

Comment: Remove the "action" attribute from your form.

Comment: How do I connect it with the controller?

Comment: you have a ng-submit="yourFunction"

Comment: in the form tag or in the input submit tag ?

Comment: When I click on the button nothing happens. edited my changes above

Comment: Think this is a mistake in linking the html and the angular part.

Comment: How does the html and the controller look? Do I have to give the filename to the controller and then to the backend?

Comment: can you please help me with the angularjs controller ?

Comment: Use the angular module I put in my answer. Check the demos, you have a working example in there.